При подключении к терминалу Linux из PowerShell Locale выставляется POSIX
Подключаюсь к своему linux серверу по ssh через PowerShell. Русский язык при этом отображается некорректно, а команда locale выдает POSIX:
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=

Если напрямую смотреть через терминал сервера, то и русский нормально отображается и locale выдает ru_RU.UTF-8

Оказалось, проблема была в опции UsePAM в файле настроек ssh /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
У меня было UsePAM no, и когда я поменял на UsePAM yes, русский язык стал корректно отображаться.
